# "cache lookup failed for type 17024" when running a series of unit tests inserting ltree in PostgresSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, flyway

I am doing a flyway migration and getting the following error message when running my tests;

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO foo_tag (
    foo_uuid,
    foo_path
) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?
)]; SQL state [XX000]; error code [0]; ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 17024; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 17024`
```

This only happens when running the tests together, and not in isolation. E.g. running `test1` and `test2` together, will make `test2` fail with the message above, but running them in isolation is fine.

```kotlin
  @Before
  @FlywayTest // Reset DB state before each test, to ensure they are independent.
  fun setUp() {
    testRepository = TestRepository(jdbcTemplate)
  }

  @Test
  fun `test1`() {
    testRepository.insertFooTag(fooUuid, "foo.bar")
  }

  @Test
  fun `test2`() {
    testRepository.insertFooTag(fooUuid, "bar.baz")
  }
```

The insertion in to the test-db looks like this

```kotlin
    @Transactional
    @Throws(DuplicateKeyException::class)
    open fun insertFooTag(
        fooUuid: UUID,
        foo_tag: String
    ) {
        val sql = """
            INSERT INTO foo_tag (
                foo_uuid,
                foo_path
            ) VALUES (
                :foo_uuid,
                :foo_path
            )
        """.trimIndent()
        
        val ltreePgObject = PGobject()
        ltreePgObject.type = "ltree"
        ltreePgObject.value = foo_tag

        val params = MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("foo_uuid", fooUuid)
            .addValue("foo_path", ltreePgObject)
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params)
    }
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem, but I assume its related to the ltree data type introduction in my db migration, which looks like this;

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "ltree";

CREATE TABLE foo_tag (
    foo_uuid UUID REFERENCES foo (uuid),
    foo_path ltree,
    PRIMARY KEY (foo_uuid, foo_path)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure *why* this fixes my problem, but adding the exact same settings I am using in my `application-db-test.properties` to a Spring profile (matching the `ActiveProfile("db-test")` I am using in my test class) makes the tests run without this error.

```
@Configuration
class TestDataBaseConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Profile("db-test")
  fun dataSource(): DataSource {
    val containerPort = "12785"
    val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:$containerPort/postgres"
    val dataSource = DriverManagerDataSource()

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
    dataSource.url = url
    dataSource.username = "foo"
    dataSource.password = "bar"
    dataSource.schema = "public"

    return dataSource
  }
}
```